# Should I make the Hbase memstore really tiny if I never write to the table?

Tags: hbase

I have a table, the data in the table is loaded through bulk-upload.  No puts take place on the table.

Does this mean, I can reduce the memstore heap size to something very small?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes go ahead as bulk loading skips the write path and does not write to WAL or memstore as it writes directly to HFile format,so memstore memory is not utilised.For reference see : http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/09/how-to-use-hbase-bulk-loading-and-why/